# Clear values modal ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I wanna clear value in the input field after I clicked the cancel button. Value in fields in form all clear and this my code building on ReactJS Use Bootstrap 4 form

```
        <div className="modal fade " id="addCateModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addCateModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="addCateModal">Create Connection Database</h5>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" 
                        onClick={()=>this.onCloseModal()}>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div className="col-10" id="centerdiv">
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Connection Name*:</label>
                                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Connection NameXXX"
                                            name="connectionName" className={'form-control' + (this.state.errors.connectionName ? ' is-invalid' : '')}
                                            onChange={(event) => this.setState({ connectionName: event.target.value })} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Database Type *:</label>
                                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                                        <Select options={listDriver} onChange={async (event) => {
                                            await
                                                event != null ?
                                                this.setState({ databaseType: event.value }) :
                                                this.setState({ databaseType: '' })
                                        }} isClearable={true} name="databaseType" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <div className="input-group" style={{ 'marginBottom': '10px' }}>
                                    <span>Connect URL :</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card col-12">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label>Host Name *</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Localhost" className="form-control" name="hostName"
                                                    onChange={(event) => this.setState({ hostName: event.target.value })} />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label>Port *</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="1433" className="form-control" name="port"
                                                    onChange={(event) => this.setState({ port: event.target.value })} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Database Name *</label>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Dbname NameXXX" className="form-control" name="databaseOfName"
                                                onChange={(event) => this.setState({ databaseOfName: event.target.value })} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-row" style={{ 'marginTop': '12px' }}>
                                    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label>User Database Connect *</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Db_user_connectXXX" className="form-control" name="userDatabase"
                                            onChange={(event) => this.setState({ userDatabase: event.target.value })} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label>Password *</label>
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" className="form-control" name="password"
                                            onChange={(event) => this.setState({ password: event.target.value })} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-right col-12">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleCheckConnection.bind(this)}>Test Connection</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-center">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Save</button>
                                <button type="reset" className="btn btn-danger ml-1" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={()=>this.onCloseModal()}>Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this's function for clear. When I press the button cancel, it cannot clear the input fields. I need other people's ideas Help me clear the data values in this form.

```
onCloseModal() {
        console.log('hello')
        this.form.clear();
        this.setState({
            connectionName: "",
            databaseType: "",
            hostName: "",
            port: "",
            databaseOfName: "",
            userDatabase: "",
            password: "",
            connectionNameEdit: "",
            databaseTypeEdit: "",
            hostNameEdit: "",
            portEdit: "",
            databaseOfNameEdit: "",
            userDatabaseEdit: "",
            passwordEdit: "",
            idConnection: ""
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you make an example of your project here: https://codesandbox.io ?
Just suggestion you may want to use https://react-bootstrap.github.io, almost the same thing but more reactish than plain html.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have the right idea Thanik. By the look of it, it seems you are not binding correctly. Try using an arrow function like below and tell me if it works for you.

```
onCloseModal = () => {

        this.setState({
            connectionName: "",
            databaseType: "",
            hostName: "",
            port: "",
            databaseOfName: "",
            userDatabase: "",
            password: "",
            connectionNameEdit: "",
            databaseTypeEdit: "",
            hostNameEdit: "",
            portEdit: "",
            databaseOfNameEdit: "",
            userDatabaseEdit: "",
            passwordEdit: "",
            idConnection: ""
        });
    }
```